# is there a "batch" file for ElasticSearch?

Tags: batch-file, elasticsearch

I have 23 ElasticSearch commands to create indexes, and during the development, i make mistakes in the data, so I delete them all.

Is there any way so I can put these commands into one file and just tell elasticsearch to execute them. In other words read that file?

#### What I have tried

I found a workarround which is, write these command to a JAVA client, and them just run that client.
It's working, but the problem is that everytime I change the commands, I have to change the query (hardcoded), in java, while I would prefer to just change it from a file, because that's easier and I would just copy paste what I try on my terminal.

thanks

#### Update

by command i mean something like this

> curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty"

but to create index and create mappings

Comment: Is this to create the mappings and possibly other index definitions? If so, you should be able to POST several mappings in one go [like this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-create-index.html#mappings).

Comment: To @linus' point, what kind of "commands" are these? At the very least, you should be able to put them into a script file (`my-commands.sh` or `my-commands.bat`).

Comment: What are the ElasticSearch commands? Could you edit your answer to contain them?

Comment: @pickypg yes that's what i 'm looking for, but how?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have some commands you execute with cmd directly. If this is correct, you can do either of the following things:

1. Create a batch file containing all the commands, which you do like
   this:

   ```
   @echo off
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   pause
   ```
2. Create a batch file to execute all commands in a text-file if you
   don't want to edit your batch-file but don't mind editing your
   text-file (for whatever reason)

   ```
   @echo off
   FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("C:\somepath\ElasticSearch.txt") DO %%G
   pause
   ```

   and create a text file called ElasticSearch.txt containing for
   example:

   ```
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   elasticSearch.exe -someparameter
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this, as Dennis sort of notes, you need to use a batch processor. However, you do not invoke Elasticsearch as a process over-and-over again. Instead, you run the *commands* that you're interested in running in the order that you want them to run.

Because you noted `curl`, presumably you are running in a Unix environment. It's literally as simple as creating a Bash Shell script that simply executes the commands in order:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/bank -d '{
  "settings" : {
    ...
  }
  "mappings" : {
    ...
  }
}'

# Do some other request (as your own example)
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty
```